# Buying tickets (1 Single and 2 Return tickets) from London to Delhi

Tags: tickets, london, new-delhi

I want to book a single ticket from London to Delhi and two Return ticket from Delhi to London.

If I book a return ticket for London - Delhi, it is costing me around 500 GBP. And if I book a single journey ticket from London to Delhi, it is costing me around 400 GBP.

My requirement is: 1 Ticket from London to Delhi and 2 Tickets from Delhi to London

And I want to make sure the 2 return ticket from Delhi to London are booked on the same flight and also the seats are together.

I have two options:

1. Buy a return ticket for London - Delhi and another single ticket from Delhi to London. Total cost would be around 900 GBP But I am not sure I will get the tickets on same flights and whether the seats will be together or not.
2. Buy a single ticket from London - Delhi and two single tickets from Delhi - London. This gonna be extremely costly to me.
   Total cost might be around 1200 GBP.

What is the best way to book tickets in such a way. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is no reason not to have the same flights on the return leg for both people.  YOU pick your flights for each ticket and just make sure they are the same.

Seats are another story, but you can call the airline and have them tie the bookings together and request seats together. If the airline charges for advanced seating, then pay the money to be sure. Then monitor the bookings as it gets closer to flight time to make sure nothing changes.

If the airline does not offer advance seat assignments, then show up early for your flight, like three hours ahead, so you have a better chance of getting seats together.  If all else fails, you can ask your row mates if they would swap seats so you can sit with your girlfriend/boyfriend/parent/whatever